# ¿Cómo separar un resultado de una columna en otra columna?

Tags: oracle

Estoy trabajando con tres tablas `Empleado`, `Estudio_Basico`, `Centro` en la cual Empleado esta relacionado con `Estudio_Basico` y Centro con `Estudio_Basico`.

Esta en mi consulta `oracle`:
[image: Consulta]

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Lo que quiero es que esa fecha que es de un mismo empleado me aparezca en otra columna para así evitar otra fila con los mismo datos en otra columna.

Comment: Por favor en vez de una imagen añade un código. También para poder entender mejor el conjunto de tablas podrías añadir la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: añade el código en formato de texto por favor

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es hacer algo así:

```
    SELECT apaemp, LISTAGG(desestbas, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY desestbas) AS fechas 
FROM (aquí pon tu select) GROUP BY apaemp;
```

No puedes añadir columnas, pero si puedes concatenar las fechas en una misma columna.